# Advantages of publishing ivy.xml on nexus?

Tags: ivy, nexus

We are in the middle of implementing Nexus in combination with ivy to do our dependency management.

We have a nexus proxy running and can succesfully publish and retrieve our artifacts using ivy:publish and a ivy:makepom target. So far this seems to work quiete nice.

I'm however left with the question whether to publish the (published version) of ivy.xml on Nexus too.
(we publish Jars, Sources, and a Pom)

When working with ivy for both publishing and retrieving artifacts are there any benefits to publishing the ivy.xml (would ivy realise it would even be there, and use the info in it?)

Comment: Yes it's possible to get Nexus to save ivy files, but other Maven modules won't have them. Far better to use the ibilio resolver which understands how to translate Maven POMs into ivy files internally. Embrace the Maven repository manager and don't try and make it do stuff it's not designed to support. Much easier to get ivy to adapt client-side.

Comment: This is what i've been doing so far just was wondering if there are advantages of storing the ivy.xml too (internally we don't / cant use maven)

Comment: I don't see any great benefit. For example I find it useful to occasionally use the Nexus UI to upload files, in that case Nexus would generate a Maven POM (not an ivy file).